# Angular JS - How to template out recursive or parent/child data?

Tags: angularjs, recursion

I am working with some data and I think that the best data structure will be a recursive parent/child relationship to represent a hierarchy.

My question is:
How to best return this data from my API to work nicely with angular?
How to use the angular to convert this into my DOM?

Many thanks
Toby

Comment: It depends how you want to represent it in your dom if you want to use ng-repeat just to loop over the you data and structure table or what not or you have something else in mind which can be more complex and that is to have a directive that calls itself recursively to do that.

Comment: Some code would help.